# Laravel 5.6 and Eloquent persisting a child model into database, can't find the hasMany or belongsTo methods from the model

Tags: eloquent, persistence, laravel-5.6

I'm using Laravel 5.6.
I have a table Product and a table ProductImages, where the ProductImages has the product_id foreign key.

On my controller, I have persisted my Product without problem and then I want to persist one or more images(ProductImages) to this Product.

I'm doing like this:

```php
$produto = Produto::find($produtoCriado);
$produto->imagens()->save(['url_imagem' => urlImagemExtra]);
```

But then I get: Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::imagens does not exist.

Produto model:

```php
class Produto extends Model {
    protected $table = 'produto';
    protected $fillable = [ 
        'nome', 'descricao_curta', 'descricao_longa', 'tags', 
        'url_imagem_principal', 'feito_por', 'feito_em', 'altura', 
        'largura', 'material'
    ];

    /***
     * Retorna as imagens relacionadas ao produto
     */
    public function imagens()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\ProdutoImagem');
    }
}
```

ProdutoImagem model:

```php
class ProdutoImagem extends Model {
    protected $table = 'produto_imagem';
    protected $fillable = [
        'url_imagem'
    ];

    /***
     * Busca o Produto relacionado a essas imagens
     */
    public function produto()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Produto');
    }
}
```

The product is saved without problems, but when I try to add the PrudutoImagem, I got the error.

Comment: To get the images, you have to tell Eloquent to get them with the produto: $produto = Produto::with('imagens')->find($produtoCriado);

Comment: I don't want to retrieve the images. I'm trying to save a new ProdutoImagem, wuch has a produto_id foreign key

Comment: What's the result of `dd($produto);`?

Comment: What is the error when you $produto->imagens()->save(['url_imagem' => urlImagemExtra]); and can you show the images model? I'm interested in the fillable fields

Answer (score 0):

If you are using save for a child class you should pass model instance as

```
$image = new ProductImage();
$image->url_imagem = urlImagemExtra;
$produto->imagens()->save($image);
```

or in simple you can use create method as

```
$produto->imagens()->create(['url_imagem' => urlImagemExtra]);
```